# Postman array schema validation

Tags: json, postman, json-schema-validator

I have the problem with array json schema validation in postman.

```
var schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": [{
         "id": {
            "type":"long"
             },
         "name": {
             "type":"string"
             },
         "email": {
             "type":"string"
            }
    }]
};


pm.test('Response schema type nodes verification', function() {
  pm.expect(tv4.validate(pm.response.json(), schema)).to.be.true;
});
```

And the response body is:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "email": "a@a.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "email": "a@a.com"
    },
 .
 .
 .
]
```

I have always passed result. Also I tried with removed `[]`.

Where is the problem?

Comment: where is validation script? have you write any test script to validate json? how you validating schema?

Comment: Of course, I have it. Edited the question.

Comment: What does your response body look like? You're only showing us the schema and not what it's validating against so how are we going to know if that `pass` result is correct or not.

Comment: The response body was added in oryginal question (edited).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The schema used in question is incorrect, you need to define the type of item in array as `object`. The correct JSON schema would look like:

```
var schema = {
    "type": "array",
    "items": [{
        type: "object",
        properties:{
         "id": {
            "type":"integer"
             },
         "name": {
             "type":"string"
             },
         "email": {
             "type":"string"
            }
        }
    }]
};


pm.test('Response schema type nodes verification', function() {
  pm.expect(tv4.validate(pm.response.json(), schema)).to.be.true;
});
```

Please note there are only 2 numeric types in JSON Schema: `integer` and `number`. There is no type as `long`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv), this is now included with the Postman native apps and the project is actively maintained:

```
var Ajv = require("ajv"),
    ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
    schema = {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": { "type": "integer" },
                "name": { "type": "string" },
                "email": { "type": "string" }
            }  
        }
    };


pm.test("Schema is valid", function() {
        pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, pm.response.json())).to.be.true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you should first parse the schema to json, else it will be considered as empty data in some cases.

The correct code is as below:

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

schema = JSON.parse(schema);
```

Now you have to pass recursive validation and nondefined property check to the tv4.validation function.

```
pm.test('Response schema type nodes verification', function() {
  pm.expect(tv4.validate(pm.response.json(), schema, true, true)).to.be.true;
});
```

tv4.validate(pm.response.json(), schema, true, true)

will check the json data recursively and if any new property is present in the resonse data, it fail the validation.